# Calculating expected number of zero-crossings of a white noise process

Tags: expected-value, frequency, white-noise

I am curious about how to calculate the expected number of zero-crossings of a white noise process over some time $t$. In particular I would like to be able to deduce the expected frequency of zero-crossing events from the calculated expectation.

I don't really know how to approach this problem. It would seem some sort of limit has to be taken on the distribution used to generate the white noise process, but it is complicated by the fact that a zero-crossing does not imply the process is zero at a given time (i.e. we are looking for crosses of the zero line AND instances when the process is valued at zero). So I do not know how to set this up.

Comment: You should clarify that you meant Gaussian white noise (which would also answer Dilip's issue), though of course it would work for any independent, symmetric, zero-mean process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my answer:

The answer to this, in general, is dependent on the distribution used to generate the white noise process. Regardless of the distribution, the process would be as follows:

1. What is the probability that the sign of the next instance's value will be opposite to the value at the current instance? Since a white noise process is valued as a random drawing from a distribution, the probability is found by simply dividing the distribution into positive and negative sections.
2. Each instance is independent of the previous instance. So, summing the expected value of whether the sign will be different for one iteration over the time $t$ gives the total number of expected crossings in the given time period. $$\sum_t [1/2(0)+1/2(1)]=(t-1)/2$$

Note: $t-1$ to account for fence-post issue.

Comment: You are, of course, assuming that the random variables have _median_ value $0$, that is, at each of the $n-1$ "gaps" between $n$ samples, a sign change is as likely to occur as to not occur, independently of all previous or future sign changes Thus the _number_ of sign changes is a _binomial_ random variable with parameters $\left(n-1,\frac 12\right)$ and so the mean value is $(n-1)/2$.